# Where to add licence?

Tags: java, open-source

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Putting license in each code file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845895/putting-license-in-each-code-file)

If I want to add a licence to my work such as the Apache Licence : http://opensource.org/licenses/Apache-2.0 or the Eclipse licence : http://opensource.org/licenses/EPL-1.0 do I need to paste the licence to every source code file or is there a generic area I can add the licence to cover all of the code base ?

Comment: @Sandro Munda thanks I got the answer I needed from your link